# Center both the label and input in a page

Tags: html, css, input, center

I had tried to center the input boxes in a form using `margin: 0 auto`, and it worked. Problem is, since the input boxes were now block-level elements, the input boxes and labels were not aligned. They were on top of the other, like a line break.

So, I figured I could wrap each label and input box inside a div, and them do the same thing I did before: `margin: 0 auto`. Unfortunately, neither the input nor the label want to center now.

CSS code:

```css
div.center{
 margin: 0 auto;
 display:block
}
```

If you guys could help me, it would be great. I can also provide my full html code and css code if there is any need.

Comment: insted of using `display:block;` try useing `display:inline-block;` might help u

Comment: I already tried that, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.center {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
}
form {
  border: solid;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="center">Label</div>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the two inputs in a div, you can add this code:

```
    .container {
        width: 50vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

If you could provide your full code I could customize it for you.